# link analysis in r and tableau

Tags: r, igraph, tableau-api

I want to conduct a link analysis in R but I want to show the results in `Tableau 9.1` I have a set of codes that I have tried to integrate in Tableau but I was lost in the integration. The set of codes is from [Yanchang Zhao shown in this link](https://rdatamining.wordpress.com/2012/05/17/an-example-of-social-network-analysis-with-r-using-package-igraph/)

and is given below:

```
load(“data/termDocMatrix.rdata”)
termDocMatrix[5:10,1:20]
termDocMatrix[termDocMatrix>=1] <- 1
termMatrix <- termDocMatrix %*% t(termDocMatrix)
termMatrix[5:10,5:10]
library(igraph)
 g <- graph.adjacency(termMatrix, weighted=T, mode = “undirected”)
g <- simplify(g)
V(g)$label <- V(g)$name
V(g)$degree <- degree(g)
set.seed(3952)
plot(g, layout=layout1)
```

Also, can we use the plot function inside the Tableau calculated field?

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: What should your output look like? and also post some sample data. for testing.

Comment: The sample data and sample is provided in the link above. I cant seem to find a button to upload the image here. Thanks!

Comment: Paste the image link here,I will upload the image for you.

Comment: Here is the link.https://i2.wp.com/www.rdatamining.com/_/rsrc/1336980493578/examples/social-network-analysis/sna-terms-1.png